# Get square shape indexes of element of 2d array

Tags: python, arrays, multidimensional-array

I want to get idexes of elemenent into 2d array by square shape

[image: Picture here]

Some more info:
Let's pretend that i need get indexes of one element of 2d array

22 33 15

65 32 16

84 26 12

Index of '33' is 01
I want get all nearest elements of it, its: 22, 65, 32, 16, 15 and indexes is: 00, 10, 11, 12, 02

So, i want get indexes like that of any element of array

So x2, for 00 elemnts its 3 neighbor, for 01 its 5 and for 11 its 8 neighbors

And some more:
How can i handle out of index value?

Sorry for my bad english

Comment: The image you provided gives a formula for each neighbor, just generate those index tuples and check if their values are out of bounds for that dimension when adding them to a collection

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
# example 2d arr
arr = [[22, 33, 15], [65, 32, 16], [84, 26, 12]]

# print
for row in arr:
   for col in row:
      print(col, end = " ")
   print()

def getNeighbours(x, y, arr):

    string = f'({x}, {y}): {arr[y][x]}'
    
    neighbours = []
    
    # get lengths for if check
    col_length = len(arr)
    row_length = len(arr[0])
    
    # distance options for x, y; loop
    for x_distance in [-1, 0, 1]:
        for y_distance in [-1, 0, 1]:
            # +0 and +0 == cur_position, so exclude
            # new x/y < 0 would be out of bounds, so exclude
            # new x/y == respective length would be out of bounds, so exclude
            # all else ok, hence: 'if not'
            if not ((x_distance == 0 and y_distance == 0) or \
            (y+y_distance < 0 or y+y_distance == col_length) or \
             (x+x_distance < 0 or x+x_distance == row_length)):
                neighbours.append(arr[y+y_distance][x+x_distance])
    
    return string, neighbours

# tests
result = getNeighbours(1, 0, arr)
print(result)
result = getNeighbours(1, 1, arr)
print(result)
result = getNeighbours(2, 1, arr)
print(result)
```

Output:

```
22 33 15 
65 32 16 
84 26 12 
('(1, 0): 33', [22, 65, 32, 15, 16])
('(1, 1): 32', [22, 65, 84, 33, 26, 15, 16, 12])
('(2, 1): 16', [33, 32, 26, 15, 12])
```

---

Update: if speed is a concern, go with the numpy solution offered by Mechanic Pig.

To clarify the `if` logic a little bit, we could also have written something like this:

```
    # distance options for x, y; loop
    for x_distance in [-1, 0, 1]:
        for y_distance in [-1, 0, 1]:
            
            # x, y coordinates for a potential neighbour
            new_x = x + x_distance
            new_y = y + y_distance
            
            if (x_distance == 0 and y_distance == 0):
                # this will lead to the element itself, so ignore
                continue
            elif new_x < 0 or new_x == row_length:
                # new_x should fall in range(row_length), so ignore
                continue
            elif new_y < 0 or new_y == col_length:
                # same for y: new_y should fall in range(col_length), so ignore
                continue
            else:
                # any other combination of ( new_x, new_y ) is OK; append element
                neighbours.append(arr[new_y][new_x])
```

Since we simply want to `continue` after `if` and 2x `elif`, we could refactor this and say: `if not (cond1 or cond2 or cond3): neighbours.append()`, as above.

Comment: but one thing i want to ask you its - would u like to rewrite one part of your example its main "logical" part in for loops. pls write its more "clearly" not in one if state. Because i want get into this by myself  but i cant with its look like this

Answer (score 0):

Consider using numpy.

```
import numpy as np

arr = np.array([[22, 33, 15], [65, 32, 16], [84, 26, 12]])
row, col = 0, 1

rows, cols = np.indices(arr.shape)

mask = np.maximum(np.abs(rows - row), np.abs(cols - col)) == 1
print(rows[mask], cols[mask])
# [0 0 1 1 1] [0 2 0 1 2]
print(arr[rows[mask], cols[mask]])
# [22 15 65 32 16]
```

I think you can master it with a little study. It's much faster than loop, and you don't need to consider the boundary problem.